# How to pull only 1 image from folder in php?

Tags: php, directory

I have working code, which pulls all images from a dynamically created folder. But I want to display only 1 image from a particular folder in my display page. Any suggestions? 
My code:

```
<?php 
    $search_dir = "$directory/{$row['name']}{$row['hotel_address']}";
    $images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
    sort($images);
    //display images
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a single image with:

```
<?php 
    $search_dir = "$directory/{$row['name']}{$row['hotel_address']}";
    $images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
    sort($images);

    // Image selection and display:

    //display first image
    if (count($images) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists
        $img = $images[0]; // first image
        echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
    } else {
        // possibly display a placeholder image?
    }

?>
```

If you want a random image, do this:

```
    // Image selection and display:

    //display random image
    if (count($images) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists

        // Get a random index in the array with rand(min, max) which is inclusive
        $randomImageIndex = rand(0, count($images)-1);
        $img = $images[$randomImageIndex]; // random image
        echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";

    } else {
        // possibly display a placeholder image
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Teddy! It really helped. Appreciated.
Actually there are many images inside each folder. What I want is, It display only 1 image at first. Once people refresh or reload page, it display next image from the respected folder randomly.

Comment: [Now it displaying only 1 image from its respective folder] 
Actually there are many images inside each folder. What I want is, It display only 1 image at first. Once people refresh or reload page, it display next image from the respected folder randomly.

Comment: Mr. Teddy! You are genius. Thank you so much. It works well and perfect.
Thanks again. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `current` to get the first image from the array.

```
<?php 
$search_dir = "$directory/{$row['name']}{$row['hotel_address']}";
$images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
sort($images);
//display one image:
echo "<img src='current($images)' height='150' width='150' /> ";
?>
```